# look for a specific match in a column and return null if that id doesn't have that value

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

My table looks like below, I want to get the records which has the description 'T02' otherwise returns null.

ID    Description
D01    T01 
D01    T02 
D01    T03 
D02    T01 
D02    T03 
D03    T01 
D03    T02 
D03    T03 
D03    T04

Expected Results

ID     Description

---

D01    T02
D02    NULL
D03   T02

I have tried to use this query but I didn't get the D02 record which has no record with the description T02.

```
  select ID, Description
   where Description =
     Case 
        when Description='T02' then Description
        else NULL end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below query using CASE and ROW_NUMBER function

```
create table #table1 (ID varchar(20), Description varchar(20))

insert into #table1 values 
 ('D01' , 'T02')
,('D01' , 'T03')
,('D02' , 'T01')
,('D02' , 'T03')
,('D03' , 'T01')
,('D03' , 'T02')
,('D03' , 'T03')
,('D03' , 'T04')


select ID, Description from (
select a.ID, case when a.Description =  'T02' then  'T02' else null end  as Description
, row_number()over(partition by a.id order by a.id, case when a.Description =  'T02' then  'T02' else null end desc) rno
from #table1 a
LEFT JOIN #table1 b on a.id =b.ID   )a where rno=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,MAX(CASE [Description] = 'T02' THEN [Description] END) AS [Description]
FROM [my_table]
GROUP BY [ID];
```

Comment: Thanks @goltn for the response. It returns null for all records as it is trying match with other records ( T03, T04). I want to find out if the left column set has the description T02 regardless of other values.

Comment: @Richard That's what the query does? Are you sure you test it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use below format and add your Table name in place of <table_name>

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Description = 'T02' THEN Description
        ELSE NULL 
        END AS ModifiedDescription
FROM <table_name>
```